# Integrate $ \int e^{-[y/b]^a} dy $

Tags: integration

I am solving the integration $\int e^{-y/b]^a} dy$,
and I tried to set $u=-[y/b]^a$,
but this way $du$ would become 
$-a [y/b]^{a-1}dy$
and the whole thing becomes 
$\int e^u \times [-[y/b]^{a-1} du]/a$.
I wonder is there any good suggestions to go on?

Thank you very much for your time and reading!
Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at this point, there's not much you can do without specific bounds or a value for $a$. The integral does not have a nice closed form solution, so the best you can do is express your answer in terms of the [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), which is basically defined as the point where you got to
$$\Gamma(\alpha,x)=\int_x^\infty e^{-t} t^\alpha dt$$

Comment: Yes, I referred to Wolfram Alpha and I noticed it might relate to Gamma function. And now I noticed that a would be put as 1. so it becomes a Gamma function. Thank you !